# Running "npm" returns "Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'"

Tags: node.js, npm, redhat, yum

```
module.js:340
throw err;
      ^
Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/npmconf/npmconf.js:3:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After exhausting other possibilities (re-installing npm and various other nodejs packages), I finally tried the simple one.  :-)

```
sudo yum install nodejs-inherits*
```

That worked for me.

Comment: this is what i got from that command on CentOS: `Package nodejs-inherits-2.0.0-4.el6.noarch is obsoleted by nodejs-0.10.40-1.shmz65.1.6.x86_64 which is already installed`

Answer (score 8):

The following worked for me. The other answer, sudo yum install nodejs-inherits*, did not do the trick for me. Note, before running the following, you may want to back up your /usr/lib/node_modules folder so you can refer back to it to recall what all you had installed globally.

```
sudo yum erase nodejs npm
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/node_modules
sudo yum install nodejs npm
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 6):

I just uninstalled and reinstalled npm:

```
brew uninstall npm
brew install npm
```

It didn't go without issue, I also had to reclaim the ownership of some libraries:

```
sudo chown -R nice /usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

and then

```
brew postinstall npm
```

Answer (score 5):

To share my info, I faced this issue, and I solved it by installing `inherits` as the following:

```
sudo npm install inherits
```

This  the github [repo](https://github.com/isaacs/inherits) of it.

Answer (score 3):

sudo yum install nodejs-inherits* didn't work for me.
Also I didn't want to erase node_modules.

Erasing inherit modules and installing/reinstalling only the new one worked:

```
sudo yum erase nodejs-inherits
sudo yum erase nodejs-inherits1
sudo yum install nodejs-inherits
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Windows recently, updating npm fixed it for me.

```
npm update npm -g
```

Comment: it gives me the exact same error

Answer (score 0):

It happend when I switch my node to version 5.5.0 by 'n'.

then I switch back to node 0.10.22,which I used befor, and run

```
npm update npm -g
```

then it is fine now

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error in Windows 7 32 bit system and fixed it by uninstalling the nodejs itself. After freshly installing the nodejs, I ran the following commands

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm-windows-upgrade -p -v latest
```

This has fixed the issue for me

Answer (score -3):

Running `npm install –y` helps me in my situation.
I don't know what `-y` option means.