# module.js:471 throw err;

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have been trying to solve this one the whole day and am at my wits end.

npm doesn't work and throws the following error whenever I try anything with it:

---

```
C:\Users\Bernh\Desktop\Coding Projects> npm -v
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Bernh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:68:17)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
```

---

I have tried:
-reinstalling nodejs
-installing different versions of nodejs
-running any npm command give the same error

I have been refereed to a few similar answers on stackoverflow, but these aren't the same as everyone uses npm to fix their npm... by npm does nothing.

Also some of the answers are for lunix command lines and I can't find any equivalent commands for windows.

I have tried an installer call choco, but doesn't seem to be able to work with the npm install/uninstall

Any solutions or suggestions?

Regards

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933077/running-npm-returns-error-cannot-find-module-inherits

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running "npm" returns "Error: Cannot find module 'inherits'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19933077/running-npm-returns-error-cannot-find-module-inherits)

Comment: @MarkoGrešak please better close-vote as duplicate instead of just downvoting

Comment: @DanFromGermany can't. I voted close for a different reason and retracted my vote and now I'm unable to submit a different close reason.

Comment: Haha ok, nvm :-)

Comment: Can't seem to get that answer to work. I'm not too good with the command line and all the answers seems to be for linux machines with "yum" ... only answers that makes sense to me are the npm ones, but I can't use a broken npm to fix npm and reinstalling nodejs in all the formats I have tried isn't solving the problem...

Answer (score 0):

After two days of work I found the problem.

I manually went into the Program Files and Program Files (x86) folders and deleted everything to do with npm and nodejs.

I then deleted XAMPP which I had installed near the time the problems occurred.

I then did a neat restart and reinstalled nodejs 6.11.4 LTS.

This seemed to have fixed the problem.

Hope this helps someone.